# AutoCam position unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, po

I'm stuck with changing position of the MultipurposeCameraRig (imported from unity packages) ! here is the line in script of the camera position I want it up (you can see the problem in the photo below)
[image: photo]

here is the line code of camera position

```
// camera position moves towards target position:

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, m_Target.position, deltaTime*m_MoveSpeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not specified.
Are you trying to change your cam pos and it is not happening or your white image is the problem? if your position is not changing then mostly problem is in deltatime * m_MoveSpeed. Firstly hopefully it is in Update or coroutine and have a check if your camera reached to the position. You should check if the mentioned value (deltatime * m_MoveSpeed)is incrementing between 0 to 1 cause Lerp works in that way. If the problem is other than this then please specify more.

Comment: i want to move the camera a little bit up ( Y axe ) so i can see the road , the problem is when i start the game the camera take by default the position you see in the picture !